# Dissolve features in ArcGIS using multiple attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dissolve

This may sound simple, apologies if I missed some earlier discussion on same subject.

- I have a big set of road data with road numbers and also zone numbers . The road names can repeat across the zones, ie Road XYZ will be there in Zone A and Zone B.

  I would like to dissolve the road line features using "Dissolve" command, but see that roads in tow zones are note merged together.

Can the dissolve command be tweaked to achieve this ?

Answer (score 5):

Back in Arc/Info days (now called Workstation), INFO allowed you to "overdefine" aliases
across multiple fields.  If they weren't neighboring, then you'd need to generate a frequency table across the multiple fields, join to that table, and use the unique ID for your dissolve.  The old way is still available, but the Dissolve tool under Geoprocessing (I'm using ArcMap 10.1) and Dissolve toolbox tool (Data Management - Generalization) allow you to select multiple fields:
[image]