# Merge or dissolve line features based on two or more attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, merge, dissolve

I am working in Arcmap 10.2 and I would like to do the following according to the example table below, but I do not have a clue on how to do this. I am working in ModelBuilder. Is there a tool for this or another easy way to do this?

[image: Lines]

The attribute table shows line features, some attributes have the same number (attribute B) and the same material (attribute A) this means that they are the extent of each other like the figure below:

[image: Line features]

If attributes have the same number and material I would like to make one Object of these ones and I would like it to sum the shape lengths. So for example ObjectID 1 and 2 will become one Object from Wood (Attribute A) with number 13324 (Attribute B) and a Shape length of 8.997 + 0.012 = 9.009. In the figure red and blue parts will be one part.

Comment: Related/duplicate, but I find this question to be better worded/illustrated: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75556/

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Dissolve (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000005n000000) tool, select your number and material fields, then click OK. I'm not sure if the lengths will be added, but a simple "Calculate Geometry" length should fix that.

Comment: Since it produces a new file, new lengths should be calculated regardless of storage format. However @Danielle will want to pay close attention to use of the multipart option. By default this is enabled and will create multipart lines, meaning if you have two disconnected sets of lines, you'll only get one feature/row for both segments. You will probably want to make sure multiparts are *not* allowed, so you have separate lines/rows for each disconnected segment sharing the same attributes (should such a case exist).